# Can't set fs.nr_open limit via sysctl

Tags: limit, ulimit, sysctl

I'm trying to set `fs.nr_open` via sysctl (for learning purpose) to different value, other than default `1048576`

These are sysctl settings after system was booted:

```
vud@ubuntu:~$ sudo sysctl -a | grep -E '(fs.nr_open|fs.file-max)'
fs.file-max = 9223372036854775807
fs.nr_open = 3048576
```

And this is pid 1 limit:

```
vud@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/1/limits | grep 'open files'
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files
```

I need to change this hard limit but I'm actually thought that sysctl change should do the trick.

In my test I'm starting an executable and checking wheather or not limits apply.

```
linda@ubuntu:/opt$ ./test-limits &
[1] 2371

linda@ubuntu:/opt$ cat /proc/2371/limits | grep 'open files'
Max open files            1024                 1048576              files
```

I assume that the value is inherited from pid 1

P.S:
I'm aware that limits can be set through `/etc/security/limits.conf` for PAM users and through `/etc/systemd/system.conf` for services. limits.conf is empty and for systemd actually I was able to create test service and set nofile to number other than 1048576.

```
vud@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status test-limits
● test-limits.service - Testing service limits
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test-limits.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-11-18 05:40:21 PST; 5s ago
   Main PID: 2237 (test-limits)

vud@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/2237/limits | grep 'open files'
Max open files            1024                 2048576              files 
    
vud@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system.conf | grep NOFILE
DefaultLimitNOFILE=1024:2048576
```

But in my case I want to experiment and see in practice how set limits through different means and stuck on sysctl for a moment.

Comment: This may help https://serverfault.com/questions/356962/where-are-the-default-ulimit-values-set-linux-centos

Comment: I've read it and unfortunately it does not help me